# Как получить массив из строки по шаблону с использованием регулярного выражения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно составить регулярное выражения для Java?

На ввод идут такие данные `"<color:#123456>Привет <color:#5A9ACE> мир"`.

А вывод должен быть

```
["<color:#123456>Привет ", "<color:#5A9ACE> мир"]
```

Вот что я смог собрать, но это не то `"(\{color:#+([a-zA-Z1-9]{6})+})+(.+)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует использовать такое выражение: `(color:#[\dA-F]{6})(.*?)(?=$|color:#[\dA-F]{6})` ([Regex101 демо](https://regex101.com/r/iDG7iK/1)):

- Группа 1: `(color:#[\dA-F]{6})` - префикс цвета с hex-значением
- Группа 2: `(.*?)` - всё, что идёт после префикса
- Положительный просмотр вперёд (positive lookahead) `(?=$|color:#[\dA-F]{6})` -- пока не найден конец входной строки или следующий префикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Java код (*добавлены угловые скобки в шаблон и входную строку*):

```java
public static String[] parse(String str) {
     return Pattern.compile("(<color:#[\\dA-F]{6}>)(.*?)(?=$|<color:#[\\dA-F]{6}>)")
        .matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1) + " - '" + mr.group(2) + "'")
        .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Можно просто использовать `.map(MatchResult::group)` для основного совпадения без дополнительного форматирования.

Тест:

```java
String str = "<color:#123456>Привет! <color:#5A9ACE> мир";
Arrays.stream(parse(str)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Результат:

```
<color:#123456> - 'Привет! '
<color:#5A9ACE> - ' мир'
```